# spring-social Facebook login doesn't set Authentication object

Tags: facebook, spring-mvc, facebook-graph-api, spring-security, spring-social

I'm using Facebook login to authenticate in my application. I use the authentication filter.

The authentication goes OK, but when it redirects back to homepage the filter doesn't seem to set the Authentication object, so calling SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() returns null. This only happens the first time when the user authorizes our app. It doesn't happen after that.

Currently to get the Authentication object set, the user has to 'login with facebook' twice. The second time it doesn't actually do any logins, the filter looks like it's picking up the cookie and does the authentication and doesn't even need to go to Facebook anymore.

So my question is why do I need to go through the filter twice? Or how can I avoid that?

Configuration looks like this:

```
    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <constructor-arg value="/login"/>
        <property name="useForward" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.gigi.web.SpringDataUserDetailsService" id="userService"/>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService"/>
        <security:authentication-provider ref="socialAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter" id="socialAuthenticationFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="authenticationManager" />
        <constructor-arg ref="userIdSource" />
        <constructor-arg ref="usersConnectionRepository" />
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionRegistry" />

        <property name="postLoginUrl" value="/home" />
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login?error&amp;social" />
        <property name="signupUrl" value="/user/signup" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInUtils">
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionRegistry"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="usersConnectionRepository"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userIdSource" class="org.springframework.social.security.AuthenticationNameUserIdSource" />

    <bean id="socialAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationProvider">
        <constructor-arg ref="usersConnectionRepository" />
        <constructor-arg ref="userService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userSocialConnectionService" class="com.gigi.web.UserSocialConnectionController"></bean>

    <bean id="usersConnectionRepository" class="com.gigi.social.SpringDataUsersConnectionRepository">
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionRegistry" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="connectionRegistry"
            class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry">
        <property name="authenticationServices">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.social.facebook.security.FacebookAuthenticationService">
                    <constructor-arg value="${facebook.app.id}" />
                    <constructor-arg value="${facebook.app.secret}" />
                    <constructor-arg value="${facebook.app.namespace}" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like spring doesn't handle that on it's own, which kinda makes sense though I feel like it should be possible for the config, rather than having to write code for it. Anyway, here's how we've done it:

```
@RequestMapping("/signup")
public String signUp(WebRequest request) {
    Connection<?> connection = providerSignInUtils.getConnectionFromSession(request);
    User user = usersConnectionRepository.createUser(connection);
    getRepository().save(user);
    providerSignInUtils.doPostSignUp(user.getId().toString(), request);
    // the following will automatically log in the user after sign up
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new SocialAuthenticationToken(connection, user, null, user.getAuthorities()));
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```